# include class and compile with g++

Tags: c++

Im a beginner in C++ and working with unix. So here is my question.

I`ve written few lines in the main-function, and i needed a function, that is defined in the c_lib - library.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "c_lib.cpp"

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

i want to execute it on the terminal, so i wrote

```
g++ -c c_lib.cpp

g++ -c main.cpp

g++ -o run c_lib.o main.o
```

Until here, there is no error report.

Then

```
./run
```

I get the error

> error: ./run: No such file or directory

What's wrong?

Comment: You always should compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -c c_lib.cpp`

Comment: why are you including `c_lib.cpp` into your `main.cpp`? Use a header file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For what is the -Wextra and the -g?

Comment: `-Wall`: turn on 'all' warnings. `-Wextra`: turn on extra warnings not turned on by `-Wall`. `-g` compile in debug mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including a `.cpp` is not usually done, usually only headers are included.  Headers usually contain the declarations that define the interface to the code in the other `.cpp`
Can you show us the source of c_lib? That may help.

As the source of c_lib is `#include`d, there is no need to compile it seperately. In fact this can/will cause errors (multiple definitions being the first to come to mind).  You should only need to do:

```
g++ -o run main.cpp
```

to compile your code in this case.
(When using a header (`.h`), you will need to compile the implementation (`.cpp`) seperately)

Compile with warnings turned on:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o run main.cpp
```

and you will get more output if there are problems with your code.

Is the `run` file being output by gcc? You can test by calling `ls` in the terminal (or `ls run` to only show the executable if it is present).

If the executable is present, it could be that it isn't marked as runnable. I'll go into that if it is a problem as it is outside the general scope of the site (though still related)

Comment: Thank you, i have the guideline the write #include "c_lib.cpp" not c_lib.h. Yes the run file isnt there, but i cant understand why.. because ive write all the commands :(

Comment: can you post the contents of `c_lib.cpp`?

Comment: now it works, but i cant see the diffrence between now and before. I just used -Wall instead of -c

Comment: @Susliks: Compilers produce error messages if there are problems. If you see messages compiling your program, there's a problem. If you see no messages, then things compile without errors or warnings. If there's no `run` being generated, then there must have been some errors. Read them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not include source file into another source. You should create a header file and put declarations there (that allows `main()` to call functions from c_lib.cpp or use global variables if any)

When you run `g++` you have to look into it's output, if operation succeed or not. In your case it failed so executable `run` was not created.

Usually you do not call compiler manually but write a `makefile` and let `make` utility to call `g++`.

Comment: @BartoszKP Nonsense, Makefiles are completely adequate for many scenarios.